# c++ calculator Using classes

Tags: c++

I made my three types of calculators. But I fail to merge them. It is skipped my 3 types of main functions. They work separately and technically, code is running. However, it's not fully working. 
Floating floatMain();  This is not working. I don't know how to fix this.  These are my main and one class.

main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"
#include "Fraction.h"
#include "Floating.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
char type;
cout << "This is a special calculator. " << endl << endl;
cout << "Select a type of calculator (v : vector, p: floating-point, f: fraction)  : ";
cin  >> type;

switch (type)
{
case 'v' :
    cout << endl << "vector calculator" << endl;
    Vector vecMain();
    break;

case 'p':
    cout << endl << "floating point calculator" << endl;
    Floating floatMain();
    break;

case 'f' :
    cout << endl << "fraction calculator" << endl;
    Fraction fracMain();
    break;
}

char choice;
cout <<endl << "Do you wish to continue? y/n: ";

cin >> choice;

if(choice == 'y')
{
    system("cls");
    main();
}
else
    cout << "Goodbye" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Floating.h

```
#ifndef FLOATING_H
#define FLOATING_H


class Floating
{
private:
    float num1;

public:
    Floating()
    {
        num1 = 0;
    }
    void floatMain();
    void getFloating();
    void showFloating();
    Floating operator+(Floating);
    Floating operator-(Floating);
    Floating operator*(Floating);
    Floating operator/(Floating);
};

#endif // FLOATING_H
```

Floating.cpp

```
#include "Floating.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Floating::getFloating()
{
cout << "Enter number : ";
cin >> num1;
}

void Floating::showFloating()
{
cout << num1;
}

Floating Floating::operator+(Floating f)
{
Floating final;
final.num1 = num1 + f.num1;

return final;
}

Floating Floating::operator-(Floating f)
{
Floating final;
final.num1 = num1 - f.num1;
return final;
}

Floating Floating::operator*(Floating f)
{
Floating final;
final.num1 = num1 * f.num1;

return final;
}

Floating Floating::operator/(Floating f)
{
Floating final;
final.num1 = num1 / f.num1;

return final;
}

void Floating::floatMain()
{
Floating f1, f2, f3;

char operation;
cout<<" Enter an operation which you like to perform (either + or - or * 
or / or s :)";

cin>>operation ;
cout<<endl<<endl;

cout<<operation<<"):"<<endl;
f1.getFloating();
f2.getFloating();


switch (operation)
{
case'+':
f3 = f1 + f2;
f1.showFloating();
cout << " + ";
f2.showFloating();
cout << " = ";
f3.showFloating();
break;

case'-':
f3 = f1 - f2;
f1.showFloating();
cout << " - ";
f2.showFloating();
cout << " = ";
f3.showFloating();
break;

case'*':
f3 = f1 * f2;
f1.showFloating();
cout << " * ";
f2.showFloating();
cout << " = ";
f3.showFloating();
break;

case'/':
f3 = f1 / f2;
f1.showFloating();
cout << " / ";
f2.showFloating();
cout << " = ";
f3.showFloating();
break;

default:
// If the operator is other than +, -, * or /, error message is shown
cout << "Error! operator is not correct"<<endl;
break;
}

}
```

Comment: `main();` has undefined behavior. You're not allowed to call `main` in C++.

Comment: Why is `floatMain` a method of the `Floating` class?

Comment: Same question for `Floating::operator*` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't the best way to program, but it will fix your immediate error. (In an ideal world you would use polymorphism [aka virtual functions + base class interfaces] to encapsulate the each calculators' behaviour behind a common interface).

```
case 'p':
{
  Floating calculator;    ///< create a calculator object
  calculator.floatMain(); ///< now call a method on it. 
}
break;
```

Comment: in an (/my) ideal world there is no runtime polymorphism, because it comes with an overhead that in principle can be avoided most of the time :P

Comment: Thanks. I tried it before, but it didn't work because I use codeblocks. Anyways, I figured it out. Thank you.